# Help with Dual Boot Windows 10 and changing from RAID to AHCI (Dell G3 3590)

Tags: dual-boot, dell, raid, ahci

So I was trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 alongside Windows. However, the Live USB doesn't recognize the 256 GB SSD where it's going to be installed, but it does recognize the additional 1 TB HDD. Investigating a bit, apparently the problem is the driver protocol used to communicate with the SSD, called RAID. I've read I have to change it to AHCI. However, I don't want to clean reinstall Windows again and I don't want to lose all my data.

So if anybody has encountered this problem, or has this computer, can you tell me your advice? How can I do it.

Thanks in advance and have a great day, wherever you are in the world!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My computer is xps15. I made it several days before.
In windows:

1. Press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and then type `msconfig`
2. Select `Boot` check `Safe boot` and `minimal`
3. Reboot. Switch the mode to achi in the BIOS.
4. And then we go into safe mode
5. The same step, but uncheck `Safe boot`
6. Reboot. And everything is done.

[image]
However, in ubuntu installed in another drive my m.2 ssd is read-only???

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a link to the resource that you came across indicating that the problem is RAID?

Without more details, I can only guess. Normally RAID is not used for controlling a single disc like this. If RAID vs. AHCI is actually the issue, there are two likely scenarios:
1) In your BIOS/UEFI settings, the disc controller is set up for software RAID rather than AHCI. In this case, you can probably just change that setting.
2) The SSD has previously been used in a software RAID array, and has software RAID metadata written to it, and this situation is more complicated.

My recommendation is to first try looking for the disc controller the SSD is attached to in the BIOS or UEFI settings (whichever you have/use) and if it says "RAID" change it to "AHCI" which is the typical standard for accessing a typical  non-RAID configuration of SAS and SATA discs.